Add column name in temp table from different table and filter according that for those columns
In my stored procedure where I am generating report in the table Age, user can define date range for which date range data needs to be come. Table Age has AgeDesc, StartDay and EndDay. Please check the example shown here:
Table Age
AgeDesc         StartDay    EndDay
-----------------------------------
 < 30            0          30
 >30 < 60        30         60
 >60 < 90        60         90
 >90 < 120       90         120

In my stored procedure i have created a temp table as below and i have added the rest of the column from Age table to temp table as
CREATE TABLE #Bills 
(
    LedgerId INT, 
    LedgerName varchar(300),
    InvoiceNumber Varchar(50), 
    InvoiceDate DATETIME,
)

DECLARE @dynamicColumn nvarchar(max)

SELECT @dynamicColumn = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(AgeDesc),',')
FROM tblAge 

-- SELECT @dynamicColumn
DECLARE @addColumn nvarchar(max);

SELECT @addColumn = STRING_AGG(' ALTER TABLE #Bills ADD ' + QUOTENAME(AgeDESC) + ' VARCHAR(100) NULL; ',' ') 
FROM tblAge         

EXEC sp_executesql @addColumn

SELECT * FROM #Bills

After select from #Bills, I am getting column name as that is perfect
LedgerId | LedgerName | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceDate | < 30 |  >30 < 60 | >60 < 90 | >90 < 120

Now i want to insert data in #bill from my select statement as per days define in tblAge for each columns like
<30 days     InvoiceDate <= GETDATE()  AND InvoiceDate >= GETDATE()-30 
for >30 <60  InvoiceDate  < GETDATE()-30  AND InvoiceDate >= GETDATE()-60
For >60 < 90 InovoiceDate < GETDATE()-60  AND InvoiceDAte >= GETDATE()-90
for >90 < 120 InovoiceDate < GETDATE()-90  AND InoviceDate >= GETDATE()-120

INSERT INTO @Bills
    SELECT * FROM 
             L.LedgerId
            ,L.LedgerName
            ,B.InvoiceNumber, 
             B.InvoiceDate
          rest for newly added column value as per provided details

How can I do this? User can insert multiple row for different date range that will be added automatically in the #Bills table so i am using this.
Please provide me your suggestions or example. I will really be thankful for that.

You did not mention what do you want under those various age columns. So I assumed InvoiceAmount
using CROSS APPLY to determine the "age" of the Invoice and pivot using conditional case expression, you can get the required result format.
The query will looks like
; with
InvoiceAged as
(
  select b.InvoiceNumber,
         b.InvoiceDate,
         b.InvoiceAmount,
         a.age
  from   Bills b
         cross apply
         (
             select age = a.StartDay
             from   tblAge a
             where  a.StartDay <= datediff(day, b.InvoiceDate, getdate())
             and    a.EndDay    > datediff(day, b.InvoiceDate, getdate())
         ) a
)
select InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN age = 0 THEN InvoiceAmount END) AS [< 30],
       SUM(CASE WHEN age = 30 THEN InvoiceAmount END) AS [>30 < 60],
       SUM(CASE WHEN age = 60 THEN InvoiceAmount END) AS [>60 < 90],
       SUM(CASE WHEN age = 90 THEN InvoiceAmount END) AS [>90 < 120]
from   InvoiceAged
group by InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate

and to make it dynamic
the age conditional case expression query
declare @age nvarchar(max);

select  @age = STRING_AGG('SUM(CASE WHEN age = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDay) + ' THEN InvoiceAmount END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(AgeDesc), ',' + char(13)) 
FROM    tblAge 

and the rest of the query
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = '
; with
InvoiceAged as
(
  SELECT b.InvoiceNumber,
         b.InvoiceDate,
         b.InvoiceAmount,
         a.age
  FROM   Bills b
         cross apply
         (
             select age = a.StartDay
             from   tblAge a
             where  a.StartDay <= datediff(day, b.InvoiceDate, getdate())
             and    a.EndDay    > datediff(day, b.InvoiceDate, getdate())
         ) a
)
select InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate,'
       + @age +
' from   InvoiceAged
group by InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate'


thanks for your reply. Actually i have a  existing stored procedure i have a new requirement where user can define the define the days for which user can view the data. Like user define Description for the column as '0-30 Days and in startDay to 0 and end day to 30. Second column  Description '>30 -<60Days' and set startDay = 31 EndDay to 61 Days. So user will get output with other columns '0-30 Days' , ' >30 -<60Days'  and for those column data will filter as GETDATE() BETWEEN GETDAY()-30, FOR '>30-60Days' for these column data will be filter as

GETDAY-30 BETWEEN GETDATE()- 60 Days.   I have totally out of scope from last 7 days made change as per above reequipment and i am getting verry baddly force by senior to complete this.  i have added my sp on  https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=4097b400-8dee-478c-9f27-ea118af6c4fc i dont under as per above requirment how can i change this sp where everything is fixed for the day and in new user can add as much days in tblAging so that  column will be added in result.

Hope you will help me for this
